# Mirroring List with Depth Values, to Nested List ~ Python

Tags: python, nested, character

I'm going after automating my rigging process, and trying to build a C4D Python script. I am trying to mirror a list based on the depth values to a nested list.

Lets say we have **a list with depth values**:

```
depth_list = [[0,'Hips'],[1,'Spine'],[2,'Spine1'],[3,'Spine2'],[4,'Neck'],[5,'Head'],[6,'HeadTop_End'],[4,'LeftShoulder']]
```

And we want this **to become a nested joint list** based on the depth values:

```
joint_list = [['Hips',['Spine',['Spine1',['Spine2',['Neck',['Head',['HeadTop_End']]],['LefShoulder']]]]]]
```

I have come this far:

```
for joint in depth_list:
    this_depth = joint[0]
    try:
        joint_list.append(0)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

This is the original data I get from the C4D tree exporter script

```
0  Hips
1      Spine
2          Spine1
3              Spine2
4                  Neck
5                      Head
6                          HeadTop_End
4                  LeftShoulder
```

And Here is an image:

> [![enter image description here][1]][1]

**And a Happy Ten Million Everyone!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this recursively, like so:

```
depth_list = [[0,'Hips'],[1,'Spine'],[2,'Spine1'],[3,'Spine2'],[4,'Neck'],[5,'Head'],[6,'HeadTop_End'],[4,'LeftShoulder']]

def construct(depth_list, current_level=0):
    output = []
    while len(depth_list) > 0:
        new_level, new_name = depth_list[0]

        if new_level == current_level:
            output.append([new_name])
            depth_list.pop(0)
        elif new_level > current_level:
            child = construct(depth_list, new_level)
            output[-1].extend(child)
        else:
            return output

  return output

print(construct(depth_list))
```

The basic idea is that you recursively traverse through the input list. Every time you encounter an element, you do one of three things:

1. If the joint is at the same level, remove the joint from `depth_list` and add it to the output (which contains all joints at this current level).
2. If the joint is one level deeper, then don't modify `depth_list` but instead recurse to get the child tree. Then, add that tree to the last element in the output list, which is the current joint. (The recursive call will also remove the correct number of elements from the `depth_list`).
3. If it's at a shallower level, give up and return and let the parent continue looping against the remainder of the `depth_list`.

Do note that this function is *destructive* -- it'll leave `depth_list` completely empty once the function is finished. If you want preserve it, make a copy of the list before calling the function:

```
copy = list(depth_list)
print(construct(copy))
```

Comment: Thank you! I really enjoyed your reply, its very constructive fun time )

Comment: Your function is correct because it returns to the proper depth. It was my mistake since the test data where not presenting a case where the depth level would become smaller again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
depth_list = [[0,'Hips'],[1,'Spine'],[2,'Spine1'],[3,'Spine2'],[4,'Neck'],[5,'Head'],[6,'HeadTop_End'],[4,'LeftShoulder']]

result = []

current_list = None
current_item = []
current_level = 0

level_dict = {}

for depth, value in depth_list:
    if depth == 0:
        if current_list:
            result.append(current_list)
            current_list = None
        current_list = current_item
        current_item.append(value)
        level_dict[0] = current_list
    elif depth == current_level:
        current_item.append(value)
    elif depth == current_level + 1:
        append_item = []
        level_dict[depth] = current_item
        current_item.append(append_item)
        append_item.append(value)
        current_item = append_item
        current_level += 1
    else:
        level_dict[depth].append(value)

if current_list:
    result.append(current_list)

print result
```

The idea is to keep track of the previous level. I also keep all of the levels safe on a dictionary to insert items on previously checked levels. For example when you are on a 6th-level item, you are waiting for the 7th-level item, but a 4th-level item appears, so you have to update the list accordingly.

**UPDATE**

I think this solution is clearer than the other. It will be slower because it will sort the input, but if you don't have inputs like 10.000 items or more, it won't make a large difference and you will gain clarity in your code. Also, this approach always puts items before levels. This function assumes you provide at least one item per level. So, given these facts, here is the solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

depth_list = [[0, 'Hips'], [1, 'Spine'], [2, 'Spine1'], [3, 'Spine2'], [4, 'Neck'], [5, 'Head'], [6, 'HeadTop_End'], [4, 'LeftShoulder'], [5, 'LeftArm'], [6, 'LeftForeArm'], [7, 'LeftHand']]

result = []
current_level = result

get_level_number = lambda item_info: item_info[0]

sorted_by_level = sorted(depth_list, key=get_level_number)
grouped_by_level = groupby(sorted_by_level, key=get_level_number)

for level_number, grouped_items in grouped_by_level:
    level = [tag for level, tag in grouped_items]
    print level_number, level
    current_level.append(level)
    current_level = level

print result
```

Comment: Very Well Done! And your explanation made me understand it better! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, i was testing it today and noticed a small issue on a bigger set.. do you mind taking a look at this set?

[[0, 'Hips'], [1, 'Spine'], [2, 'Spine1'], [3, 'Spine2'], [4, 'Neck'], [5, 'Head'], [6, 'HeadTop_End'], [4, 'LeftShoulder'], [5, 'LeftArm'], [6, 'LeftForeArm'], [7, 'LeftHand']]

Comment: I think it work as expected to me. What's the issue? The output for me is: [['Hips', ['Spine', ['Spine1', ['Spine2', ['Neck', ['Head', ['HeadTop_End', 'LeftForeArm', ['LeftHand']]], 'LeftArm'], 'LeftShoulder']]]]]

Comment: Yes, the nesting is broken at HeadTop_End
Could you please check it out?

 [
  ['Hips', 
   ['Spine', 
    ['Spine1', 
     ['Spine2', 
      ['Neck', 
       ['Head', 
        ['HeadTop_End']
       ]
      ],
      ['LeftShoulder',
      ['LeftArm',
       ['LeftForeArm',
        ['LeftHand']
       ]
      ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]

Comment: OK, I'm gonna create a new solution for this problem, I think it's gonna be pretty neat.

Comment: This sounds like a sentence that brings out trust! Thanks avenet!

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that it still nests the leftshoulder to headtopend. Ill take a look at it at later, i wouldn't mind if you solved it thought. Thanks for all your help avenet!